# How is whitespace in an aria-label handled?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

How is extra whitespace inside an [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-label_for_link_purpose) treated? Is it ignored/trimmed like in HTML, or will it end up as pauses in screen readers?

```
<a href="blah" aria-label="    Go     to    my     site   ">...</a>
```

Comment: I think this depends more on the AT itself than what the standard says. I can't imagine whitespace being treated any differently here compared to in regular text.

Answer (score 3):

I tested this using NVDA on windows with Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE, and Edge. All browsers ignored the whitespace and read "Go to my site" without pause.

While I can't say definitively that this behavior will be the same for all AT, I highly suspect that it will be due to the [HTML 5 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/semantics.html#common2) recommending that browsers design their HTML parsing engines to drop consecutive spaces.

Additionaly, the CSS `white-space` property doesn't seem to have any effect either (at least on NVDA).

If you're looking to achieve some specific result, you may be interested in the Deque article entitled [Why Don’t Screen Readers Always Read What’s on the Screen?](https://www.deque.com/blog/dont-screen-readers-read-whats-screen-part-1-punctuation-typographic-symbols/#grammatical), which has some very useful reference material regarding how the major screen readers handle various forms of punctuation. If you want to create a pause between words, for example, you could use commas or periods, which would yield similar results across platforms.

As a caveat, I'd recommend doing your own testing (where possible), using multiple browsers, operating systems, and AT, just to confirm that the behaviors haven't changed in the 4-5 years since that article was written.